# Pandas - Check for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a data set that I want to implement three layers of checks

a) if all values in Col B are duplicates then print("all dupes")
b) if last 8 values in Col B are duplicates then print("last 8 are dupes")
c) if last 5 values in Col B are duplicates then print ("last 5 dupes")

Dataframe:

```
        Col A  Col B
    0    XYZ    452
    1    ZXP    452
    2    ABZ    452
    3    CDP    452
    4    XEF    452
    5    ZRT    452
    6    XXX    452
    7    YYY    452
    8    DDD    452
    9    EEE    452
   10    FFF    452
   11    ZZA    452
```

I was trying the all dupes case first:

```
if df.['Col B'].duplicated.all():
    print("all dupes")

elif df.['Col B'].tail(8).duplicated.all():
    print("last 8 dupes")

elif df.['Col B'].tail(5).duplicated.all():
    print("last 5 dupes")

else:
    print("no dupes")
```

but it goes straight to "no dupes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change by remove `.` and add `()` for [`Series.duplicated()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), if need test all duplicates add `keep=False` parameter:

```
df.['Col B'].duplicated.all()
```

to:

```
df['Col B'].duplicated(keep=False).all()
```

All together:

```
if df['Col B'].duplicated(keep=False).all():
    print("all dupes")

elif df['Col B'].tail(8).duplicated(keep=False).all():
    print("last 8 dupes")

elif df['Col B'].tail(5).duplicated(keep=False).all():
    print("last 5 dupes")

else:
    print("no dupes")
```

You can test column only once and then select last values of mask `m`:

```
m = df['Col B'].duplicated(keep=False)

if m.all():
    print("all dupes")

elif m.tail(8).all():
    print("last 8 dupes")

elif m.tail(5).all():
    print("last 5 dupes")

else:
    print("no dupes")
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, I completely misinterpreted the explanation of the keep=False parameter in the documentation, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np

if len(np.unique(df['Col B']))==1:
    print("All dupes")
elif len(np.unique(df['Col B'].tail(8)))==1:
    print("last 8 dupes")
elif len(np.unique(df['Col B'].tail(5)))==1:
    print("last 5 dupes")
else:
    print("no dupes")
```

Comment: thank you, hadn't thought of the np approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that [duplicated method of DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) can accept column label, so you might use it following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['XYZ','ZXP','ABZ'],'B':[452,452,452]})
print(df.duplicated('B', keep=False).all())
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: it was the keep=False parameter part in your answer, also as per jezrael's reply above, thank you for your time :)